# How do I view the JSON from a WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, json

I have set up a WCF service. I have programmed the URL to be in the format:

```
http://localhost:64136/NewsProvider.svc/Rest/Getnews/1
```

When I set the return type to be XML I can change the number at the end of that link and browse the xml in a browser. However when I change it to JSON as soon as I hit the page in firefox I am asked do I want to download it?

How do I get round this and just view the pure JSON. When I used to write a page that wrote JSON I would add the following:

```
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        Response.Write(json);
        Response.End();
```

But I dont see how to change the content type and mess with the response object with WCF?

And will changing the content type actually let me just view the raw xml in the browser what govers this?

Comment: You can use a free program called fiddler. Its a developers proxy and it will show you all the requests and response in json,raw,xml.. etc that's what we use

Comment: Yeah fiddler isnt working for me when I make this request! :-(

Comment: yea localhost might not work :( i have this issue sometimes too. try it from live site. or like ladislav said. try to install some plugin.

Answer (score 4):

Yes firefox will offer you to open or download the content and if you do it you will see the passed JSON. If you don't like it you should install some Firefox extension (like [JSONView](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jsonview/)) or HTTP proxy (like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)).

Comment: But then why didnt firefox force me to 'save' the JSON when it was plaintext? And how to I force the MVC to change the content type?

Comment: Simply firefox doesn't open documents with content-type `application\json` and changing the content type is not a solution. That can break functionality in clients which expects JSON.